# $\int_0^\infty \sin{(e^{ax})}dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I have to check convergence of $\int_0^\infty \sin{(e^{ax})}dx$?

I tried with substitution $e^{ax}=t$ for $a>0$ and got $\int_1^\infty \frac{\sin{t}}{at} dt$. This integral converges.

For $a=0$ I got divergent integral. I'm having doubts about convergence for $a<0$, is integral also convergent in this case?

Am I right so far?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $a<0$, $\sin(e^{ax})\sim e^{ax}$ and the integral converges.

Answer (score 2):

If $a<0$, $t=e^{ax}$ gives $\int_0^1\frac{\sin t}{-at}dt$. The integrand has $t\to0^+$ limit $-1/a$ and is bounded on $(0,\,1]$, and so the integral converges.